# How to attain the period of this nonlinear differential equation/system?

Tags: calculus, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

Lately, I've been trying to find the period of an angle included in the following differential equations, but only could with the basic model:

Basic or original: $$\mathrm{For}\ (\Phi (0), \Omega (0))=(\Phi_{o},0),\ \frac{d^2\Phi}{dt^2}= \frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\sin{\Phi}-\frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\zeta\ \mathrm{sgn\ \Phi}\ ;$$
Modified: $$\mathrm{For\ the\ same\ initial\ conditions},\ \frac{d^2\Phi}{dt^2}= \frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\frac{\sin{\Phi}}{f(\Phi)}-\frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\zeta \frac{\mathrm{sgn\ \Phi}}{f(\Phi)}\ -2\dot{\Phi}^2 \frac{f'(\Phi)}{f(\Phi)}.$$

Where $g$ is gravity, $\ell_{o}$ is the length of the inverted pendulum, $\zeta$ a group of other constants, $\operatorname{sgn}\left(\cdot\right)$ is the signum function, $\dot{\Phi}=\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$, $f(\Phi)=\sqrt[3]{1-\eta\cos{\Phi}}$ ($\eta$ is another constant) and $f'(\Phi)=\frac{df(\Phi)}{d\Phi}$.

And so, the method I used to get the period was basically this:

Let $F(\Phi)= \frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\sin{\Phi}-\frac{g}{\ell_{o}}\zeta\ \mathrm{sgn\ \Phi}$ , then the diff. eq. reduces to $\frac{d^2\Phi}{dt^2}=F(\Phi).$ And now I just proceed.
\begin{align}
  \int \frac{d^2\Phi}{dt^2}d\Phi &= \int F(\Phi)\ d\Phi\\
  \frac{1}{2}\dot{\Phi}^2 &= \int F(\Phi)\ d\Phi\ +C\\
  \dot{\Phi} &= \frac{d\Phi}{dt} = \sqrt{2\int F(\Phi)\ d\Phi +C}\\
  \frac{T}{4}=\int_{t_{o}}^{t_{1}}dt &= \int_{0}^{\Phi_{o}}\frac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{2\int F(\Phi)\ d\Phi +C}}\\
  T &=2\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\Phi_{o}}\frac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{\int F(\Phi)\ d\Phi +C}}.
\end{align}

This worked for the basic model; but didn't for the modified one. The issue was the integral of $F(\Phi)$ since in the modified version it included all terms divided by $f(\Phi)$ and also the $\dot{\Phi}^2 \frac{f'(\Phi)}{f(\Phi)}$ one too. Can someone tell me any easier way to attain the period of this modified system? Or what approximation could I use to make it easier to deal with?

[image]

Comment: I just copied another publication I had on the mathematics server since I thougt it would be suitable too for this physics server. I just copy-pasted the code and thought that the operator name and alignment were some kind of error so I got rid of them. Sorry. Do as you please.

Comment: There's an indicator at the bottom of the post that someone edited it (and if you click on the time stamp of that indicator, it shows you the history). In any event, your ODE has a problem when $\Phi=\cos^{-1}(1/\eta)$ as $f(\Phi)=1/0\equiv\text{undef}$ at this point.

Comment: Yes, I noticed later. As what you're saying, this shouldn't pose a problem since $-70º ≤ \Phi ≤ 70º$ and $0 ≤\eta ≤ 0.9$ or $1$ at max. .

Comment: I finally edited it into what it was originally.

Comment: Actually, once $\Phi=0$, then $\sin(\Phi)=\operatorname{sgn}(\Phi)=f'(\Phi)=0$ and thus, $d^2\Phi/dt^2=0$. So it looks like you don't actually have a periodic function.

Comment: It should be periodic. Look at the graph I just added in the publication.

Comment: Well what you wrote is not surely periodic, since it very clearly remains 0 once reaching that value. Are you sure what you wrote in your post the same thing that was used in generating that figure? I doubt that they are the same (especially considering $\Omega$ is not defined in your post).

Comment: It is exactly the same. I think it has to do with $\Omega$ since in the condition you mentioned $\Phi$ and $\frac{d^2\Phi}{dt^2}=0$, but $\Omega = \frac{d\Phi}{dt}= $ constant, so there'd still be angular momentum, thus keeping on moving. My only guess.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to tell you then. $\Omega=\dot{\Phi}$. Sorry about that.

Comment: I take back much of what I said, as the numeric method shows periodicity. Hope my answer helps, though it's not an analytic one.

Comment: Thanks, the answer you provided, is it to find the period or to find the solution to the modified differential equation? Also, for $\zeta ≤ 1$, the maximum value $\Phi_{o}$ can get is (at equilibrium) $\pm \arcsin{\zeta}$, so if it is surpassed the inverted pendulum should fall over. If $\zeta > 1$, then you can input any $\Phi_{o}$ as long as it does not surpass $\pm$70º-80º at most. As for the values used in my plot: $l_{o}≈1$; $\eta = 0.8$, and $\zeta = \frac{V^2}{g\ R_{sc}}≈ 1.05$. I also wrote a code to get the period (depending on the initial conditions) for the basic model.

Answer (score 0):

This likely isn't going to be the answer you want, as it obtains a numeric solution instead of analytic one. But this is still an approach I would take in finding it or searching for a parameter space.  The general idea would be to solve this as a pair of first-order ODEs:
\begin{align}
  \dot{\phi} &= \chi \\
  \dot{\chi} &= F\left(t,\,\phi,\,\chi\right)
\end{align}
From which you can use an ODE solving method you like (e.g., RK4). In Python, you could use [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) to solve the ODE for you (assuming you have a good time span at the onset). I left a couple parameters ($\eta$, $\zeta$ and $\ell_0$) as `?` as their values aren't really indicated in the post.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# define constants..
ETA = ?
ZETA = ?
G = 9.81
L0 = ?
GL0 = G / L0

def df(phi: float) -> float:
  """ derivative of f w.r.t. phi """
  num = np.sin(phi)
  if abs(num) < 1e-10:
    return 0
  return ETA * num / (3.0 * (1.0 - ETA * np.cos(phi))**(2.0 / 3.0))


def f(phi: float) -> float:
  """ function f() """
  return (1.0 - ETA * np.cos(phi))**(1.0 / 3.0)


def evolve(z: np.ndarray, t: float) -> np.ndarray:
  """ evolution function """
  chi, phi = z
  dchi = GL0 * np.sin(phi) - GL0 * ZETA * np.sign(phi) - 2.0 * df(phi)
  dphi = chi
  return np.array([dchi / f(phi), dphi])


def ode(phi_init: np.ndarray):
  """ solve the ODE problem given initial conditions """
  t_span = np.arange(0.0, 6.0 * np.pi, 0.05)
  solution, output = odeint(evolve, phi_init, t_span, full_output = True)
  # plot solution
  phi, phidot = solution.T
  plt.plot(t_span, phi, label=r"$\Phi$")
  plt.plot(t_span, phidot, label=r"$\Omega$")
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

And then calling the ode function with whatever initial conditions you want. Using $\ell_0=12$, $\eta=0.15$ and $\zeta=0.25$ with $\Phi_0=\pi/4,\,\Omega=0$, I get the following,

[image]

Presumably you can replicate the image in the original post using whatever parameters the source indicates. Toying around with some of the parameters, it looks like $\zeta$ is a likely larger than 1.

Comment: How could I approach a parameter space? I'm new to this...

Comment: The parameter space is just the set of $\eta,\,\zeta,\,\ell_0$ that give good/reasonable periods of $\Phi$ (mostly to search for min/max values of the period). If you have physical arguments that one (or more) of these are constrained to a single value (which looks that way for $\zeta$, given your last comment on the question), then you can remove it from the parameter space.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.